# Protractor find item in repeat and click it

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to find a speaker by name in repeater. And the speaker is found click the edit button.

The test I got so far fails miserably :(. Anyone got a lead?

**View:**

```
<div ng-repeat="speaker in $ctrl.speakers">
  <div class="name" ng-bind="speaker.name"></div>
  <button name="editbutton" title="edit" ng-click="$ctrl.onEdit(speaker)"></button>
</div>
```

**Protractortest:**

```
it('should remove Bill Gates', async function () {
    await browser.get(speakerLink); //url to page
    await browser.driver.sleep(200);

    let speakers = await element.all(by.repeater('speaker in $ctrl.speakers'));
    await speakers.isPresent();

    await speakers.then(function (speakers) {
        let description = element(by.model('speaker.name'));
        if (description.getText() == ('Bill Gates')) {
            await element(by.name('editbutton')).click();
        }
    });
    await browser.driver.sleep(5000);
});
```

**Protractor error**

Protractor fails with the error

```
    await element(by.name('editbutton')).click();  
          ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)    at Module._compile (module.js:588:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at C:\Users\ralf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:93:
```

**More info**

Running node v8.6.0

Using plain vanilla javascript (for the moment, planning on moving to typescript/webpack)

Comment: `Unexpected identifier` tells me you don't use an ES6-ready interpreter, or you don't have an async function. You do have the latter, so: what do you run your code with? What version of node?

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans Updated my question

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best solution but this is how I have implemented the same thing and it works just fine. I hope this helps.

```
  this.openCategory = function (category) {
element.all(by.repeater('page in section.pages')).then(function (rows) {
  rows.some(function (row) {
    row.getText().then(function (value) {
      if (value === category) {
        log.info('[PASS] - Category:' + ' ' + category + ' ' + 'matched the value:' + ' ' + value + ', ' + 'that is shown on UI.');
        row.click()
          .then(function (value) {
            log.info('[PASS] - Category:' + ' ' + category + ', ' + 'clicked.');
          });
      }
    });
  });
});
```